# Merge Vector Layers fails on point layers with no log output

Tags: qgis, shapefile, layers, merge

I'm trying to merge three layers in QGIS 3.10.14. Each layer contains only points and displays correctly in my map view.

When I use the `Merge vector layers` menu option, I get the correct dialogue box. I then use the `...` button next to the `Input layers` field and hit `Select all` in the resulting child dialogue box. However, when I hit `OK`, both that child dialogue box and the parent dialogue box vanish, with no new layer being created, and with no error being shown.

I tried looking at the `log` tab in the `merge vector layers` dialogue box to see if there's any output there. But nothing seems to show up.

Any ideas about where I can find more useful information on what's going wrong?

**EDIT**: I'm using the three layers of rail stations from https://septaopendata-septa.opendata.arcgis.com/

I've tried deleting all fields from all three layers before attempting the merge of the point layers, and that does not fix the situation.

Comment: If it is possible, delete all fields then merge. Or at least if you have some common id field, like FID, drop that. If you just want to keep the geometries I can post a pyqgis script I use to merge many layers

Comment: Thanks to you both. I have tried removing the fields, and it does not appear to help. Which files would I edit in vim to combine the points?

Comment: I see 4 Data Categories in your link: Regional Rail Data, Trolley Data, Bus Data, and Highspeed Data. Where to go from there?

Comment: I suggest updating to see if the bug is still present in a supported version.

Comment: I can only find two layers "Highspeed stations" and "Regional rail..:" these merges without any problems

Comment: Thanks everybody. I'll try merging just the highspeed stations and the regional rail stations, without the trolley stations (which I don't really need anyway). If that fails, I'll try updating QGIS to the latest version.

Comment: An update: Upgrading to version 3.22.2 seems to have fixed the problem. If somebody makes that into an answer, I'll approve it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to QGIS 3.22.2 fixed this problem.